Uncaught Error: useNatureRecord must be used within a NatureRecordProvider in React Native TypeScript app
I'm developing a React Native app with TypeScript and using Firebase for data storage. In my app, I have a context provider (NatureRecordProvider) that should wrap two main screens, NatureRecordForm and RecordStorage. However, when I navigate to these screens, I encounter the following error in my web server:
Error Message:
enter image description here
The full error trace suggests that useNatureRecord is being used outside of the NatureRecordProvider, though I believe I've wrapped the necessary components with the provider.
Here’s a summary of my setup:

Context Setup:


NatureRecordProvider is defined in RecordContext.tsx and provides several functions (addEnvironmentalRecord, addBiologicalRecord, etc.) to manage records.
useNatureRecord is a custom hook to access the context.


Navigation Configuration:


RecordNavigation component wraps NavigationContainer with NatureRecordProvider.


Component Usage:


NatureRecordForm and RecordStorage are both accessed via RecordNavigation.

Code Samples:

RecordNavigation.tsx:

const RecordNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NatureRecordProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="NatureRecordForm">
          <Stack.Screen name="NatureRecordForm" component={NatureRecordForm} />
          <Stack.Screen name="RecordStorage" component={RecordStorage} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NatureRecordProvider>
  );
};


RecordStorage.tsx

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Alert, View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { useNatureRecord } from '../../RecordLogic/RecordContext'; // Adjust the path as needed
import TopBanner from '../../RecordComponents/TopBanner';
import TabNavigation from '../../RecordComponents/TabNavigation';
import { NatureRecord as ImportedNatureRecord, NatureRecord } from '../../RecordLogic/NatureRecordInput';

interface LocalNatureRecord extends ImportedNatureRecord {
  sliders: any;
}

const RecordStorage: React.FC = () => {
  console.log("NatureRecordStorage component rendered");

  const { environmentalRecords: rawEnvironmentalRecords, biologicalRecords: rawBiologicalRecords, fetchRecords } = useNatureRecord();
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState<string>('environmental');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecords();
  }, []);

  const environmentalRecords: LocalNatureRecord[] = rawEnvironmentalRecords.map(record => ({
    ...record,
    id: record.id || 0, // Ensure id is present
  }));
  
  const biologicalRecords: LocalNatureRecord[] = rawBiologicalRecords.map(record => ({
    ...record,
    id: record.id || 0, // Ensure id is present
  }));

  const handleClosePress = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "닫기",
      "정말 닫으시겠습니까?",
      [
        { text: "취소", onPress: () => console.log("Close canceled"), style: "cancel" },
        { text: "확인", onPress: () => console.log("Close confirmed") }
      ]
    );
  };

  const handleTabPress = (tab: string) => {
    setSelectedTab(tab);
  };

  const { EnvironmentalRecordsList, BiologicalRecordsList }: { EnvironmentalRecordsList: React.FC<{ records: LocalNatureRecord[]; }>; BiologicalRecordsList: React.FC<{ records: LocalNatureRecord[]; }>; } = createRecordLists();

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, padding: 0, margin: 0 }}>
      <TopBanner 
        source={require('C:\\app\\my-app\\NatureImg\\close.svg')} 
        text="도감"
        onClosePress={handleClosePress}
      />
      <TabNavigation onTabPress={handleTabPress} selectedTab={selectedTab} />
      <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        {selectedTab === 'environmental' && (
          <EnvironmentalRecordsList records={environmentalRecords} />
        )}
        {selectedTab === 'biological' && (
          <BiologicalRecordsList records={biologicalRecords} />
        )}
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );

  function createRecordLists() {
    const EnvironmentalRecordsList: React.FC<{ records: NatureRecord[]; }> = ({ records }) => (
      <View>
        {records.map((record, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={styles.recordContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.reviewText}>{record.review}</Text>
            <Image source={{ uri: record.photo }} style={styles.photo} />
            {record.sliders.map((slider: { name: string; value: number; }, sliderIndex: number) => (
              <Text key={sliderIndex} style={styles.sliderText}>{slider.name}: {slider.value}</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );

    const BiologicalRecordsList: React.FC<{ records: NatureRecord[]; }> = ({ records }) => (
      <View>
        {records.map((record, index) => (
          <View key={index} style={styles.recordContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.reviewText}>{record.review}</Text>
            <Image source={{ uri: record.photo }} style={styles.photo} />
            {record.sliders.map((slider: { name: string; value: number; }, sliderIndex: number) => (
              <Text key={sliderIndex} style={styles.sliderText}>{slider.name}: {slider.value}</Text>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
    return { EnvironmentalRecordsList, BiologicalRecordsList };
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  recordContainer: {
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  reviewText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  photo: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  sliderText: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
});

export default RecordStorage;


NatureRecordForm.tsx

import React, { useState, useMemo, useCallback } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Alert, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { useNatureRecord } from '@/RecordLogic/RecordContext';

import SaveButton from '@/RecordComponents/SaveButton'; 
import ReviewComponentStyle from '@/RecordStyle/ReviewComponentStyle'; 
import TopBanner from '@/RecordComponents/TopBanner';
import SliderComponent from '@/RecordComponents/SliderComponent';
import PhotoDisplay from '@/RecordComponents/PhotoDisplay';
import BigQuestionStyle from '@/RecordStyle/BigQuestionStyle';

const initialSliders = [
  { name: '탐험한 곳은 얼마나 아름다웁니까?', value: 50 },
  { name: '다른사람에게 이곳을 탐험하는 걸 추천하고 싶으면 어느정도?', value: 50 },
  { name: '탐험하는 동안 얼마나 즐거웠나요?', value: 50 },
  { name: '탐험하는 동안 얼마나 가치있었나요?', value: 50 },
  { name: '탐험 난이도는 어느정도 였나요?', value: 50 },
];

const labels = [
  { text: '아름다움' },
  { text: '추천 수준' },
  { text: '즐거움' },
  { text: '가치' },
  { text: '난이도' },
];

const NatureRecordForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [review, setReview] = useState('');
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState('');
  const [sliders, setSliders] = useState(initialSliders);
  const [inputHeight, setInputHeight] = useState(40); // Initial height for the TextInput
  const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
  const { addEnvironmentalRecord } = useNatureRecord();

  const memoizedSliders = useMemo(() => sliders, [sliders]);

  const handleAddRecord = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const newRecord = {
        id: Date.now(), // Generate a unique id
        review,
        photo,
        sliders: memoizedSliders,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(), // Ensure timestamp is in a consistent format
      };

      await addEnvironmentalRecord(newRecord);

      Alert.alert('Record saved successfully!');
      navigation.navigate('RecordStorage'); // Navigate to RecordStorage page
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving record: ', error);
      Alert.alert('Failed to save record.');
    }
  }, [review, photo, memoizedSliders, addEnvironmentalRecord, navigation]);

  const handleSave = useCallback((data: { name: string; value: number }[]) => {
    setSliders(data);
  }, []);

  const handleClosePress = useCallback(() => {
    Alert.alert(
      "뒤로 넘어가면 기록이 삭제되는데 괜찮습니까?",
      "",
      [
        { text: "취소", style: "cancel" },
        { text: "확인", onPress: () => console.log("Close confirmed") }
      ]
    );
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, padding: 0, margin: 0 }}>
      <TopBanner 
       source={require('C:\\app\\my-app\\NatureImg\\close.svg')} 
       text="자연환경 도감 등록"
       onClosePress={handleClosePress}
      />
      {photo ? <PhotoDisplay photoUri={photo} /> : null}
      <View style={BigQuestionStyle.container}>
        <Text style={BigQuestionStyle.howWouldYou}>탐험을 하셨군요!{'\n'}{'\n'}다음을 평가해주세요!</Text>
      </View>
      <SliderComponent initialSliders={memoizedSliders} onSave={handleSave} labels={labels} />
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 20 }} />
      <View style={ReviewComponentStyle.inputContainer}>
        <View style={ReviewComponentStyle.inputWrapper}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder="한 줄 입력"
            value={review}
            onChangeText={setReview}
            style={[ReviewComponentStyle.input, { height: inputHeight }]}
            multiline
            onContentSizeChange={(e) => setInputHeight(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="사진 URL 입력"
        value={photo}
        onChangeText={setPhoto}
        style={ReviewComponentStyle.photo}
      />
      <View style={styles.buttonWrapper}>
        <SaveButton title="기록 저장" onPress={handleAddRecord} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonWrapper: {
    marginVertical: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default React.memo(NatureRecordForm);


RecordContext.tsx

import React, { createContext, useState, useContext, ReactNode, useEffect } from "react";
import { collection, addDoc, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { db, storage } from '@/firebase';

interface NatureRecord {
  id: number;
  photo: string;
  review: string;
  sliders: { name: string; value: number }[];
}

interface NatureRecordContextProps {
  environmentalRecords: NatureRecord[];
  biologicalRecords: NatureRecord[];
  addEnvironmentalRecord: (record: NatureRecord) => Promise<void>;
  addBiologicalRecord: (record: NatureRecord) => Promise<void>;
  fetchRecords: () => Promise<void>;
}

const NatureRecordContext = createContext<NatureRecordContextProps | undefined>(undefined);

export const NatureRecordProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  console.log("Provider rendering"); // Add this line to check if the provider is rendering

  const [environmentalRecords, setEnvironmentalRecords] = useState<NatureRecord[]>([]);
  const [biologicalRecords, setBiologicalRecords] = useState<NatureRecord[]>([]);

  const addEnvironmentalRecord = async (record: NatureRecord) => {
    console.log("Adding environmental record", record); // Debugging log
    try {
      let photoURL = '';
      if (record.photo) {
        const storageReference = ref(storage, `photos/${Date.now()}_${record.photo}`);
        const response = await fetch(record.photo);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        await uploadBytes(storageReference, blob);
        photoURL = await getDownloadURL(storageReference);
      }

      const newRecord = {
        ...record,
        photo: photoURL,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      };

      await addDoc(collection(db, 'environmentalRecords'), newRecord);
      setEnvironmentalRecords([...environmentalRecords, newRecord]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving record to Firebase: ', error);
    }
  };

  const addBiologicalRecord = async (record: NatureRecord) => {
    console.log("Adding biological record", record); // Debugging log
    try {
      let photoURL = '';
      if (record.photo) {
        const storageReference = ref(storage, `photos/${Date.now()}_${record.photo}`);
        const response = await fetch(record.photo);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        await uploadBytes(storageReference, blob);
        photoURL = await getDownloadURL(storageReference);
      }

      const newRecord = {
        ...record,
        photo: photoURL,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      };

      await addDoc(collection(db, 'biologicalRecords'), newRecord);
      setBiologicalRecords([...biologicalRecords, newRecord]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving record to Firebase: ', error);
    }
  };

  const fetchRecords = async () => {
    console.log("Fetching records"); // Debugging log
    try {
      const environmentalSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'environmentalRecords'));
      const biologicalSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'biologicalRecords'));

      const environmentalData = environmentalSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })) as unknown as NatureRecord[];
      const biologicalData = biologicalSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })) as unknown as NatureRecord[];

      setEnvironmentalRecords(environmentalData);
      setBiologicalRecords(biologicalData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching records from Firebase: ', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecords();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NatureRecordContext.Provider value={{ environmentalRecords, biologicalRecords, addEnvironmentalRecord, addBiologicalRecord, fetchRecords }}>
      {children}
    </NatureRecordContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useNatureRecord = () => {
  const context = useContext(NatureRecordContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useNatureRecord must be used within a NatureRecordProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

Troubleshooting Steps:

Confirmed that NatureRecordProvider wraps NavigationContainer.
Checked that useNatureRecord is only called within components under RecordNavigation.

Questions:

Why am I receiving this error even though NatureRecordProvider appears to wrap the necessary components?
Could this be related to the navigation structure or async data loading within the provider?

Any guidance on resolving this error would be greatly appreciated!
I expected the NatureRecordProvider context to provide data to all components within the navigation stack, as I wrapped the navigation stack in NatureRecordProvider. I anticipated that useNatureRecord would work within both NatureRecordForm and RecordStorage without error. However, instead, I encountered the error message: “useNatureRecord must be used within a NatureRecordProvider.”

Here are a couple of things you could consider:
First, your import statements are different:
NatureRecordForm: import { useNatureRecord } from '@/RecordLogic/RecordContext';
RecordStorage: import { useNatureRecord } from '../../RecordLogic/RecordContext';
Ensure they are pointing to the same useNatureRecord function within the same Context.
Secondly, try moving Navigator and Provider into App.tsx to ensure all components are wrapped and re-validate. This way you will also debug if there are any components missing the ProviderWrapper
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import RecordNavigation from './RecordNavigation';
import { NatureRecordProvider } from './RecordContext';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NatureRecordProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <RecordNavigation />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </NatureRecordProvider>
  );
};

export default App;


It has been resolved. Thank you.

I found that the error occurred in the _layout.tsx section when creating an app in React Native. After wrapping the _layout.tsx part like this, the error was resolved. Thank you! When developing apps or websites, it’s often difficult to spot errors clearly, just like creating algorithms. I think I struggled with this for about three weeks.
// app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { useColorScheme } from 'react-native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { TabBarIcon } from 'C:\\app\\my-app\\components\\navigation\\TabBarIcon';
import NatureRecordForm from './NatureRecordForm';
import BiologyRecordForm from './BiologyRecordForm';
import RecordStorage from './RecordStorage';
import NatureDetails from './NatureDetails';
import BiologyDetails from './BiologyDetails';
import { NatureRecordProvider } from '@/RecordLogic/RecordContext';

export default function Layout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();

  return (
    <NatureRecordProvider>
      <Tabs.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
          headerShown: false,
        }}>
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="NatureRecordForm"
          component={NatureRecordForm}
          options={{
            title: 'Nature Record Form',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'leaf' : 'leaf-outline'} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="BiologyRecordForm"
          component={BiologyRecordForm}
          options={{
            title: 'Biology Record Form',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'leaf' : 'leaf-outline'} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="RecordStorage"
          component={RecordStorage}
          options={{
            title: 'Record Storage',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'leaf' : 'leaf-outline'} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="NatureDetails"
          component={NatureDetails}
          options={{
            title: 'Nature Details',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'leaf' : 'leaf-outline'} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          name="BiologyDetails"
          component={BiologyDetails}
          options={{
            title: 'Biology Details',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, focused }) => (
              <TabBarIcon name={focused ? 'leaf' : 'leaf-outline'} color={color} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </NatureRecordProvider>
  );
}

